# Graph Excel API: How to set Calculation Mode (to improve performance)

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

How do I change the Calculation Mode between manual and automatic?
In the March 5th Graph API [Community Call](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/microsoft-graph-community-call-march-5-2019/), Joe Zhoa (slide 21) indicated you can set the CalculationMode (Auto-reCalc). However, I cannot figure out how. And I can't find any documentation on it (I also looked in beta documentation).
If it's not released yet, when might it be?

I am interested in setting CalculationMode to manual when setting multiple values, then have it calculate before getting values. I'm hoping it will help to improve performance when we need to set values into multiple ranges. Currently using DependsOn and/or small batch sizes is quite slow. I am hoping that with CalculationMode set to manual, we can set multiple values concurrently in batches of 20 (or more when supported) without dependsOn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the entire calculation feature is not quite clear. I was able to change the calculation mode only by opening the workbook in Excel, setting the calculation mode to manual in the Options menu and saving back to Sharepoint. 
After that, if you GET 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/application
, it will return "calculationMode": "Manual".
To calculate, POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/application/calculate.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbookapplication-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbookapplication-calculate?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs

Comment: Ability to get calculation mode and calculate are very good. However, I'd also like to be able to set calculation mode (to manual):  user won't always remember to do that before saving.